# How to change a value outside, when inside a Dispatch Semaphore (Edited)

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency, dispatchsemaphore

i have a question, and I will tell you as clear as possible:

I need to get an object to my func, create a variable version of it, change some property values one by one, and use new version of it for saving to the cloud. My problem is, when I declare my variable, if I change property values inside my Dispatch Semaphore, the variable outside not changing somehow, there is some problem that I could not understand. Here is the code :

```swift
    func savePage(model: PageModel, savingHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    // some  code .....
    
    var page = model // (1) I created a variable from function arg
    
    let newQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "image upload queue")
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    newQueue.async {
        if let picURL1 = model.picURL1 {
            self.saveImagesToFireBaseStorage(pictureURL: picURL1) { urlString in
                let url = urlString   // (2) urlString value true and exist
                page.picURL1 = url    // (3) modified the new created "page" object
                print(page.picURL1!)  // (4) it works, object prints modified
            }
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    semaphore.wait()

    newQueue.async {
        if let picURL2 = model.picURL2 {
            self.saveImagesToFireBaseStorage(pictureURL: picURL2) { urlString in
                let url = urlString
                page.picURL2 = url
            }
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    semaphore.wait()

    print(page.picURL1!) //(5) "page" object has the old value?
    
    
    newQueue.async {
        
        print(page.picURL1!) //(6) "page" object has the old value?
        
        do {
            try pageDocumentRef.setData(from: page)
            savingHandler(true)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error writing city to Firestore: \(error)")
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    } 
    semaphore.wait()
}
```

I should upload some pictures to the cloud and get their urls, so I can create updated version of the object and save onto the old version on the cloud. But "page" object doesn't change somehow. When inside the semaphore, it prints right value, when outside, or inside another async semaphore block, it prints old value. I am new to the concurrency and could not find a way.

What I tried before :

- Using Operation Queue and adding blocks as dependencies.
- Creating queue as DispatchQueue.global()

What is the thing I am missing here?

Edit : I added semaphore.wait() after second async call. It actually was in my code but I accidentally deleted it while pasting to the question, thanks to Chip Jarred for pointing it.

**UPDATE**

This is how I changed the code with async - await:

```swift
func savePage(model: PageModel, savingHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Some code
    
    Task {
        do {
            let page = model
            let updatedPage = try await updatePageWithNewImageURLS(page)
        // some code
        } catch {
        // some code
        }
    }
    
    // Some code
}

private func saveImagesToFireBaseStorage(pictureURL : String?) async -> String? {
    //some code
    return downloadURL.absoluteString
}

private func updatePageWithNewImageURLS(_ page : PageModel) async throws -> PageModel {
    let picUrl1 = await saveImagesToFireBaseStorage(pictureURL: page.picURL1)
    let picUrl2 = await saveImagesToFireBaseStorage(pictureURL: page.picURL2)
    let picUrl3 = await saveImagesToFireBaseStorage(pictureURL: page.picURL3)
    let newPage = page
    return try await addNewUrlstoPage(newPage, url1: picUrl1, url2: picUrl2, url3: picUrl3)
}

private func addNewUrlstoPage(_ page : PageModel, url1: String?, url2 : String?, url3 :String?) async throws  -> PageModel {
    var newPage = page
    if let url1 = url1 { newPage.picURL1 = url1 }
    if let url2 = url2 { newPage.picURL2 = url2 }
    if let url3 = url3 { newPage.picURL3 = url3 }
    return newPage
}
```

So one async function gets a new photo url, for an old url, second async function runs multiple of this first function inside to get new urls for all three urls of the object, then calls a third async function a create and return an updated object with the new values.

This is my first time using async - await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your first `async` call:

```swift
newQueue.async {
    if let picURL1 = model.picURL1 {
        self.saveImagesToFireBaseStorage(pictureURL: picURL1) { urlString in
            let url = urlString   // (2) urlString value true and exist
            page.picURL1 = url    // (3) modified the new created "page" object
            print(page.picURL1!)  // (4) it works, object prints modified
        }
    }
    semaphore.signal()
}
```

I would guess that the inner closure, that is the one passed to  `saveImagesToFireBaseStorage`, is also called asynchronously.  If I'm right about that, then `saveImagesToFireBaseStorage` returns almost immediately, executes the `signal`, but the inner closure has not run yet, so the new value isn't yet set.  Then after some latency, the inner closure is finally called, but that's after your "outer" code that depends on `page.picURL1` has already been run, so `page.picURL1` ends up being set afterwards.

So you need to call signal in the inner closure, but you still have to handle the case where the inner closure isn't called.  I'm thinking something like this:

```swift
newQueue.async {
    if let picURL1 = model.picURL1 {
        self.saveImagesToFireBaseStorage(pictureURL: picURL1) { urlString in
            let url = urlString 
            page.picURL1 = url    
            print(page.picURL1!)
            semaphore.signal() // <--- ADDED THIS
        }
        /*
        If saveImagesToFireBaseStorage might not call the closure,
        such as on error, you need to detect that and call signal here
        in the case as well, or perhaps in some closure that's called in 
        the failure case.  That depends on your design.
        */
    }
    else { semaphore.signal() } // <--- MOVED INTO `else` block
}
```

Your second `async` would need to be modified similarly.

I notice that you're not calling `wait` after the second `async`, the one that sets `page.picURL2`.  So you have 2 calls to `wait`, but 3 calls to `signal`.  That wouldn't affect whether `page.picURL1` is set properly in the first `async`, but it does mean that `semaphore` will have unbalanced waits and signals at the end of your code example, and the blocking behavior of `wait` after the third `async` may not be as you expect it to be.

If it's an option for your project, refactoring to use `async` and `await` keywords would resolve the problem in a way that's easier to maintain, because it would remove the need for the semaphore entirely.

Also, if my premise that `saveImagesToFireBaseStorage` is called asynchronously is correct, you don't really need the `async` calls at all, unless there is more code in their closures that isn't shown.

### Update

In comments, it was revealed the using the solution above caused the app to "freeze".  This suggests that `saveImagesToFireBaseStorage` calls its completion handler on the same queue that `savePage(model:savingHandler)` is called on, and it's almost certainly `DispatchQueue.main`.  The problem is that `DispatchQueue.main` is a *serial* queue (as is `newQueue`), which means it won't execute any tasks until the next iteration of its run loop, but it never gets to do that, because it calls `semaphore.wait()`, which blocks waiting for the completion handler for `saveImagesToFireBaseStorage` to call `semaphore.signal`.  By waiting it prevents the very thing its waiting for from ever executing.

You say in comments that using `async`/`await` solved the problem. That's probably the cleanest way, for lots of reasons, not the least of which is that you get compile time checks for a lot of potential problems.

In the mean time, I came up with this solution using `DispatchSemaphore`.  I'll put it here, in case it helps someone.

First I moved the creation of `newQueue` outside of `savePage`.  Creating a dispatch queue is kind of heavy-weight operation, so you should create whatever queues you need once, and then reuse them.  I assume that it's a global variable or instance property of whatever object owns `savePage`.

The second thing is that `savePage` doesn't block anymore, but we still want the sequential behavior, preferably without going to completion handler hell (deeply nested completion handlers).

I refactored the code that calls `saveImagesToFireBaseStorage` into a local function, and made it behave synchronously by using a `DispatchSemaphore` to block until it's completion handler is called, but only in that local function. I do create the `DispatchSemaphore` outside of that function so that I can reuse the same instance for both invocations, but I treat it as though it were a local variable in the nested function.

I also have to use a time-out for the `wait`, because I don't know if I can assume that the completion handler for `saveImagesToFireBaseStorage` will always be called.  Are there failure conditions in which it wouldn't be?  The time-out value is almost certainly wrong, and should be considered a place-holder for the real value.  You'd need to determine the maximum latency you want to allow based on your knowledge of your app and its working environment (servers, networks, etc...).

The local function uses a key path to allow setting differently named properties of `PageModel` (`picURL1` vs `picURL2`), while still consolidating the duplicated code.

Here's the refactored `savePage` code:

```swift
func savePage(model: PageModel, savingHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
{
    // some  code .....
    
    var page = model
    
    let saveImageDone = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let waitTimeOut = DispatchTimeInterval.microseconds(500)

    func saveModelImageToFireBaseStorage(
        from urlPath: WritableKeyPath<PageModel, String?>)
    {
        if let picURL = model[keyPath: urlPath]
        {
            saveImagesToFireBaseStorage(pictureURL: picURL)
            {
                page[keyPath: urlPath] = $0
                print("page.\(urlPath) = \(page[keyPath: urlPath]!)")
                saveImageDone.signal()
            }
            
            if .timedOut == saveImageDone.wait(timeout: .now() + waitTimeOut) {
                print("saveImagesToFireBaseStorage timed out!")
            }
        }
    }
    
    newQueue.async
    {
        saveModelImageToFireBaseStorage(from: \.picURL1)
        saveModelImageToFireBaseStorage(from: \.picURL2)
        print(page.picURL1!)
        
        do {
            try self.pageDocumentRef.setData(from: page)
            
            // Assume handler might do UI stuff, so it needs to execute
            // on main
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async { savingHandler(true) }
        } catch let error {
            print("Error writing city to Firestore: \(error)")
            
            // Should savingHandler(false) be called here?
        }
    }
}
```

It's important to note that `savePage` does *not* block the thread that's called on, which I believe to be `DispatchQueue.main`.  I assume that any code that is sequentially called after a call to `savePage`, if any, does not depend on the results of calling `savePage`.  Any that does depend on it should be in its `savingHandler`.

And speaking of `savingHandler`, I have to assume that it might update the UI, and since the point where it would be called is in a closure for `newQueue.async` it has to be explicitly called on `DispatchQueue.main`, so I do that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   I added semaphore.wait() after second async call int the question now. It actually was in my code but I accidentally deleted it while pasting to the question, thanks you for pointing it. Unfortunately it doesn't work after changing the code as you suggested, it freezes app entirely if I move semaphore.signal() to inside. I'll try refactoring to use async and await too thank you for suggesting

Comment: Freezing sounds like `saveImagesToFireBaseStorage` executes its closure on the same queue as your calls to `wait`, probably `DispatchQueue.main`.  Because it's a *serial* queue, if it's waiting for the semaphore, it can never go to the next iteration of its run loop where it would execute queued up closures, so the wait is blocking the signal.  That's why it's better not to block at all, if you can avoid it.

Comment: Refactoring with async and await now solved my problem.

Comment: Good!  I'm glad something about my answer helped.  I actually just wrote up a solution using `DispatchSemaphore` given the freezing behavior, and was about to update my answer with it.  I'll do that anyway, so it'll be there for the next person, but honestly using `async`/`await` is probably the cleanest solution.